# wso2 Identity Server Your account is not active

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am adding test users to Identity Server. I can not login with them because I get an error in the logs that state

Your account is not active

How can I activate these dummy accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a user and assign user role(s) (admin/everyone or custom defined role) to the created user. Give necessary **Permissions** to the user role.

Are you using standalone IS? Can you give exact steps to reproduce the issue.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: I am using a stand alone IS that I configured to use external LDAP for user mgt. I enter as admin , create a new user with roles ad admin , identity, and everyone. I logout. I attempt to login using the new user and am unsuccessful.

Comment: I removed the tenant-mgt.xml i had included in the repository/conf directory , restarted and now it allows me to login.